# Update text file whitout losing information

Tags: java, file, class, text, bufferedwriter

this part of code replace information in file, how to save information and everytime update It? I mean I want have like a history of answers in text file.

```
try {
    File file = new File("src/test/History.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write("bla bla bla");
    bw.close();


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate as suggested by icrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to open your file in append mode. To do so, you must add a boolean in the FileWriter constructor.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

See the [FileWriter documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) for more infirmations.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to append to a file that you have previously written to, use:

```
FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)
```

Comment: Yes, I want append. And how in my code must look this line? I need to delete my `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());`?

Comment: No, just add the argument `true` to the FileWriter constructor